# Where do I place and manage the profile information in a custom IDP setting?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to understand the responsibilities of an IDP (identity provider).

I am given the duty to implement an API and an in-company-use IDP. IDP uses OpenID Connect Authorization Code Flow with PKCE protection. The user credentials that are crucial for authentication and authorization such as email and password are managed by the IDP.

However, I am not sure where to put and how to manage the user profile information such as birth date, given name, etc. I am guessing these should also go to the identity provider. But then for example how do I update these things? Does IDP become an API itself? Does that make sense? Do I also need to create an additional API scope for the IDP in the access token?

Answer (score 0):

IDPs normally are also able to manage the user profile information of users, such as given_name, family_name and more. The OpenID Connect standard also defines a few aspects in regard to this, especially the user info endpoint ([OpenID Connect UserInfo Endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo)) or Standard claims ([OpenID Connect Standard Claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims)).

To update user profile information the IDPs offer APIs to update the user and its profile information. Some also provide you with a user self service portal which you can integrate into your application.